# Error to execute SSIS package. Missing ODBC component

Tags: ssis, odbc

appreciate for advice.

We trying to load data from as400 iSeries database to mssql with odbc connection. From data tool ok to load.. but the deployed package encountered this issue..

I have no luck on getting solution by googling the error message.

msg 1: LOAD SIBS DATA:Error: There were errors during task validation.
msg 2: LOAD SIBS DATA:Error: SIBS failed validation and returned error code 0xC0048021.
msg 3: LOAD SIBS DATA:Error: One or more component failed validation.
msg 4: LOAD SIBS DATA:Error: The component is missing, not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The contact information for this component is "ODBC Source;Connector for Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) by Attunity; Attunity Ltd.; All Rights Reserved; http://www.attunity.com;6".
msg 5: LOAD SIBS DATA:Error: The version of SIBS, clsid {F8600F4A-E321-42F4-AA59-DA00FA374EA5} is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
msg 6: LOAD SIBS DATA:Error: The version of SIBS is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.

[image]

Comment: You should copy the errors to your question so that it can be picked up by searches.

Comment: oh yea.. sorry .. let me do it now

Comment: was it fixed? I have the same error and interested in an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the TargetServerVersion parameter value matches your SSIS/SQL server version. This parameter can be found in your Visual Studio project properties: Configuration Properties -> General -> TargetServerVersion